# How do I get the paths of networked computers in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to get the paths of all the computers connected to my network.

Is there a function like `Directory.GetDirectores()` to retrieve a list of paths?

Comment: Is this an out of browser Silverlight application, or an in browser one?

Comment: Note that if it is in-browser one you'll run into sandboxing and not be able to get any local information - so please answer @cost comment to clarify your question.

Comment: @tnw I can't apply that solution. I can't import DirectoryServices

Comment: @tyuo9980 Retracted vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. As this is a Silverlight application running within the browser, it will be running within a sandbox, which offers very little access to the underlying machine. To my knowledge you cannot do this with silverlight.

You may (emphasis on may) be able to write something that handles this manually by recreating the underlying protocol that identifies local machines, but at best silverlight offers you sockets on a very specific range of ports (see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/06/23/why-does-silverlight-have-a-restricted-port-range-for-sockets.aspx) for more information) so I don't think it's actually feasible.